# USB activity monitoring

Tags: forensics

Is there any method or tool which will allow to monitor activity on USB? With activity I mean if you can by any chance see if files like (`pdf, jpeg, doc,` etc, ...) was copied or opened on USB device.

Comment: Are you looking for spyware recommendations?

Comment: @skooog No. I am looking for forensics tool.

Comment: Wireshark now has a USB monitoring module.  Have you looked at that?

Comment: So, it looks like you are not concerned with USB or even monitoring. You want to know how to know if any file has been accessed. (Monitoring != forensics) Could you edit your question to reflect the broader definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three timestamps normally recorded:

- `mtime` - updated when the file contents change. This is the
  "default" file time in most cases.
- `ctime` - updated when the file
  or its metadata (owner, permissions) change
- `atime` - updated when
  the file is read

For your need you will need `atime`, so you can open your USB device in terminal:

```
user@ubuntu:/media/USB-2477$
```

and run: `ls -l --time=atime myfile.pdf`

This will return to you when was the last time when you accessed that file. For copying the file I'm not sure if that will be recorded.

Or use `stat` it has similar function:

```
 stat --printf="Change %z\nAccess %x\nModify %y\n" myfile.pdf
```

It will return:

```
Change 2017-09-27 21:06:23.000000000 
Access 2017-09-27 22:04:00.000000000 
Modify 2017-08-11 21:36:40.000000000
```

Comment: as long as you don't mount the filesystem with noatime or readonly (which one might choose to do on write-limited devices)

Comment: Also note that these times can be changed arbitrarily, they are in no way secure.

Comment: For ext4 at least (which I assume since you're using Ubuntu), there are also two other hidden timestamps, `crtime` (called `btime` on some filesystems) which records the creation time of the file, and `dtime` which marks the time of inode deletion. They are both recorded, just not accessible through `stat()`.